# How to aggregate across documents from nested documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, group-by, aggregate, children

I have documents that look like this:

Document 1

```
{
   Name: "Test",
   Items: [
        { Type: 1, Value: 1 },
        { Type: 2, Value: 2 },
        ...
   ]
}
```

Document 2

```
{
   Name: "Test",
   Items: [
        { Type: 1, Value: 10 },
        { Type: 2, Value: 20 },
        ...
   ]
}
```

Now I need to group on the `Name` and `Type` fields across multiple documents then average value.  But I am struggling to find information on how you can do this with elastic search?

In MongoDB for instance I would `$unwind` `Items` then ``` $group``Name ``` and `Items.Type` then `$avg` `Value` field.

The results I am expecting are:

Result 1

```
{
    Name: "Test,
    Type: 1,
    Average: 5.5
}
```

Result 2

```
{
    Name: "Test,
    Type: 2,
    Average: 10.5
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
For nested documents you can run aggregation like the below one...


"aggs" : {
    "resellers" : {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "resellers"
        },
        "aggs" : {
            "min_price" : { "min" : { "field" : "resellers.price" } }
        }
    }
}
```

for the mapping of data like...

```
"product" : {
    "properties" : {
        "resellers" : { 
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
                "name" : { "type" : "string" },
                "price" : { "type" : "double" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source : http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html

Comment: I have read that documentation and it seems it work directly on 1 document not several.